# casting timestamp as date oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, to-date

I have this Timestamp field which looks like this:
**2015-08-24 16:24:28.763915**
and I want to get only the date and insert to date field

I tried this:

```
select
TO_DATE(CAST (CON1.AF_UPDATE_DT AS VARCHAR(10)), DD/MM/YYYY)
FROM AF_EMR_MEM_CONT CON1
```

but i get this error

> **00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"**

If I try to do this sql:

```
select AF_UPDATE_DT
       TO_DATE(CAST (CON1.AF_UPDATE_DT AS VARCHAR(10)), YYYY/MM/DD)
FROM AF_EMR_MEM_CONT CON1
```

I get the error:

> **00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"**

Comment: A `date` column still has a time part in Oracle. If you want to set the time to `00:00:00` use `trunc(AF_UPDATE_DT)`

Answer (score 1):

You can just truncate the TIMESTAMP, result of the TRUNC function is DATE:

```
SELECT TRUNC(LOCALTIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SUBSTR`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php) to extract the date portion from the string, and then [`TO_DATE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) to modify it to a date object:

```
select TO_DATE(
  SUBSTR('2015-08-24 16:24:28.763915', 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD') -- 2015-08-24
from DUAL
```

See this **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/5785)**

Comment: Thank you
I tried your solution and it worked great!